# jQuery .css -= value doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

first I'm sorry but the fiddle will not work because the problem is about a code applied on a free forum platform unmanageble `file-per-file` because it is entirely hosted `forumcommunity.net`, and for its security, their owners disabled by default MANY JS Features (the most important), the PHP and the "$" for jQuery.
Now, there is a workaround but I'll give you the corrected code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rTbhh/2/

The problem is with

```
objs.o.on("click", function() { $(".color").css("font-size", "-="+objs.val); });
```

It seems to not working because `-=` seems to not exist but on jQuery docs there's a reference about the use of `+=` and `-=` in .css function.
I tried this also in Google Chrome js Console.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What is `objs` and (by extension) `objs.val`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol objs is an object with, inside, N, O, VAL and ACTUAL "variables".

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara what? What do you mean? It doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide better examples, I actually had to write half of your fiddle to make it work.

What happens is that += and -= in jQuery take integer arguments, rounding respectively up and down. So when you have .5 for your val, the font-height is increased by 1 and decreased by 0.

Comment: Thank you for answering me.
You are saying that my code is "a little bit" wrong?
So, what I have to do?

Comment: in fact it's ***both*** increased and decreased by `0`, I doubt that `font-size` can only be an interger (otherwise it will be rounded). This ***+= and -= in jQuery take integer arguments*** appears to be wrong, because if you try with `opacity` (instead of `font-size`), it will accept a float number.

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti your code is wrong in how you increase and decrease the `font-size`, the minimum increment/decrement is `1`, but you used `0.5`. After setting `font-size = font-size + 0.5`, it's in fact rounded to `font-size` which is unchanged, so it won't work. If you change `0.5` to `0.8`, it in fact works but the actual increment/decrement is `1` (rounded from `0.8`) (not `0.8`).

Comment: This is the situation:

I'm in a forum where some classes and Ids are defult; some of them could be edited, others no.
The class mini_buttons is where "Edit topic" and "Quote answer" are.
So I prepend 2 buttons: A+ and A-
Now, when I click one of them, the font of .color (the class that defines topic text css properties) get increased and decreased.
I can't use opacity because I don't need them. I need only to increase the font and decrease it, but -= doesn't work (tried also in pure javascript). Anyway thankyou @KingKing.

Comment: @KingKing Yep, I am wrong and you are correct about the opacity. This is what I got from fiddling with the fiddle - when I put the value to 1.5 it increased the font by 2 and decreased it by 1 for every click. Beats me!
AlexanderCerutti just change your val variable to some integer and you'd be fine

Comment: Anyway, @KingKing you were right, I saw that if I click the first time, it get 12.5 (font-size + val) and then It increases of 1...

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti I talked about `opacity` as an example to prove that `+=` and `-=` can accept a float (not just integer as this answer showed). About your font-size, as I said you can only increase/decrease your font-size by the minimum value of `1` (you are currently set it as `0.5` in `objs.val`). It's so obvious.

Comment: @KingKing what about parseFloat? (yes I'm newbie)

Comment: Okay, Okay, I understand: there's no more ways...

Anyway, thank you @KingKing and for the trying todorodev.